# Drop index given criteria on multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am trying to drop rows that belong to a given index when a certain criteria is met. In this case, I want to drop an index when all values that belong to that index, are NaT.

I've tried using the following code, but the dropna method doesn't solve the problem.

```
   import pandas as pd 
   df_dict = {'id':['001','002','002','003','003'],'req_dat':['2018-11-20','2018-12-13','2018-12-23','2018-12-27','2018-12-30'],'app_date':['2018-11-21','NaT','2018-12-24','NaT','NaT'],'can_date':['2019-02-21','NaT','2019-01-25','NaT','NaT']} 
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
   df1 = df.set_index(['id','req_dat'])
   df2 = df1.dropna(how='all')
```

This is the original dataframe:

```
                  app_date    can_date
id  req_dat
001 2018-11-20  2018-11-21  2019-02-21
002 2018-12-13         NaT         NaT
    2018-12-23  2018-12-24  2019-01-25
003 2018-12-27         NaT         NaT
    2018-12-30         NaT         NaT
```

I'm getting this result:

```
                  app_date    can_date
id  req_dat
001 2018-11-20  2018-11-21  2019-02-21
002 2018-12-23  2018-12-24  2019-01-25
```

And I'm expecting this, where the row with req_dat = 2018-12-13 isn't dropped, because it belongs to id = 002 and not **all** rows belonging to id = 002 are NaT, hence no row should be dropped:

```
                  app_date    can_date
id  req_dat
001 2018-11-20  2018-11-21  2019-02-21
002 2018-12-13         NaT         NaT
    2018-12-23  2018-12-24  2019-01-25
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean to have a `NaT` row? A row with all  columns being `NaT` or just any column being `NaT`? An please, put an example where some rows get deleted

Comment: Both rows belonging to index 003 are being deleted, I can add the original dataframe before applying the dropna method. I meant all colmuns being NaT, I'll edit that too. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `transform` and `max`:

```
df1[df1.groupby(level=0).transform('max').notna().all(1)]
```

---

```
                 app_date   can_date
id    req_dat                         
 1  2018-11-20 2018-11-21 2019-02-21
 2  2018-12-13        NaT        NaT
    2018-12-23 2018-12-24 2019-01-25
```

Answer (score 2):

You should groupby on `id` in this case `level 0`, then check if `all` the rows of that group are `NaT`. Then use boolean indexing to keep the rows which are not all `NaT`:

```
m  = df.set_index(['id', 'req_dat']).groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x.isna().all()).all(axis=1)
df[~m.values]
```

**Output**

```
    id     req_dat   app_date   can_date
0  001  2018-11-20 2018-11-21 2019-02-21
1  002  2018-12-13        NaT        NaT
2  002  2018-12-23 2018-12-24 2019-01-25
```